# Getting exception on second call to web service

Tags: cxf, sslhandshakeexception

I have a service that I call (using cxf to create the client code).  After deploying I can make my first service call with no problem.  However on my second call I get the following error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException 
invoking https://ifsy-soa-dev01.oracleoutsourcing.com:443/soa-infra/services/Publishers/ItemAddSyncMasterItemListEBMPublisher/item-add-dev-send-to-PS:

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target

What is strange is that on my local development Weblogic server I don't see this issue. Has anybody resolved this issue before?

Much thanks in advance!